# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type

Tags: c++, string, char

i need your help !
This is my Code :

```
strName = pWeapon->GetInvenNormalIcon();
```

strName is a string ! and the return of GetInvenNormalIcon too !
But now the problem ! I need to set that string on a char* var !
I try to do by that way

```
pWeapon->szName         = strName;
```

But i get that error

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type
```

What i have to do ? Thanks

Comment: You need try to convert `std::string` to `char*`.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to help you sensibly. Should `pWeapon->szName` be pointer to allocated memory for instance? If so, how will it be freed? Try to submit an [mcve] if you can.

Answer (score 1):

If `strName` is `std::string` you have to use `strName.c_str()` method to to get `const char*` pointer to its content. However you should understand, that if `strName` is a local variable, it will be freed on function exit, so your `pWeapon->szName` pointer will became dangling. Perhaps it is better to make it `std::string` too.

**Upd:** However like @songyuanyao rightfully pointed out, `c_str()` method returns `const char*`, so you could not use it directly. You should allocate memory first, and then copy string content to it.

```
pWeapon->szName = new char[strName.length() + 1];
strcpy_s(pWeapon->m_mData, strName.length()+1, strName.c_str());
```

You will have to free `pWeapon->szName` in class destructor and make sure, that memory is not leaked out when you reassign pointer. Since `std::string` does all this stuff automatically, better use it instead of pointers.

Comment: "use strName.c_str() method to to get char* pointer". No, you'll get `const char*`.